# How can i get Internet certificates into Notes ID File programatically?

Tags: x509certificate, lotus-domino

Blockquote

I have imported my internet certificate into my Notes ID File. I am interested to use an Notes application that get this certificate to make a digital signature of some data o file. Can I access to this internet certificate whithin Notes?

Thank you

Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the Notes C API provides any calls for access keys or certificates stored in the ID file.  Instead, it provides features for using the keys to sign, encrypt or decrypt data notes.